# setPersistenceEnabled(true) and FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, pagination, firebaseui

I am using Firebase Database Local Persistence:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

And also using pagination `FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter`.

The issue I am facing is that new values added to `Firebase Realtime Database` is not been updated on `RecyclerView`, even if I restart listening to the database. I mean, I close and reopen the `Activity` where the listener is contained and I always get the old data.

It seems that I am always retrieving the local database instead of the updated data in the `Firebase Realtime Database`.

I would like to use both features.

1) Why am I always getting the old data?

2) Is it possible to use both features without getting this kind of issue? If yes, how?

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Are you sure you have internet connection on user's device?

Comment: yes. First, I added some data (lets say data1) to the `Firebase Realtime Database` and tested on my physical device. After that, I changed `Firebase data` to data2 and tested both my emulator and physical device. On the emulator I get data2 and in my device I get data1. Later I changed `Firebase to data3 and my emulator keeps showing data2 and my device keeps showing data1.

Comment: @AlexMamo I've just confirmed, I've disabled `setPersistenceEnabled(true)` to the emulator and it always gets the updated data while my device keeps showing the old data.